# Ajax does not work, instead starts default method and action

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-submit

So my problem is that ajax (or something else) does not work for a form, and what is the most strange is that there is one form which does work perfectly with AJAX. I've tried a lot of things: changed `input` with `button` and for it the type from `"submit" to "button"`, tried to use another method from jQuery `.post()` and `.get()`, tried to use `xmlHttpRequest`. I am very confused now. Maybe you can see something what i can't.Thanks

EDIT: So, i've modified it a little and got this error in the console (by now there where not any errors).
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Xfj.png)

Html form

```
<form action="./contactAction.php" method="POST" class="contact_form" id="cform"name="contactForm">
        <input type="text" name="contactFname" placeholder="Prenumele" />
        <input type="text" name="contactLname" placeholder="Numele" />
        <input type="text" name="contactEmail" placeholder="Emailul tau" />
        <textarea name="contactSubject" placeholder="Scrie mesajul tau" style="height: 200px"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="contactBtn">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#contactBtn").click(() => {
    contactFormValidation();
});
```

});

```
function contactRequest() {
let fname = $("#contactFname");
let lname = $("#contactLname");
let email = $("#contactEmail");
let subj = $("#contactSubject");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../contactAction.php",
    data: ({"constactFname": fname, "contactLname": lname, "contactEmail": email, "contactSubject": subj}),
    dataType: "html",
    success: (response) => {
        alert("Request success");
        //$("#loginPage").html(response);
    },
    error: () => {
        alert("Error :(");
    }
});
return false;
```

}

```
function contactFormValidation() {
let $form2 = $("#contactForm");
$form2.validate({
    wrapper: "div",
    debug: false,
    rules: {
        contactFname: {
            required: true
        },
        contactLname: {
            required: true
        },
        contactEmail: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        contactSubject: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: () => {
        alert("Submit calledd");
        contactRequest();
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few syntactical errors in your code.

1. Your selectors aren't valid.

From the looks of it, you're trying to fetch the value based off the `name` attribute. For this to work, you'll need the selector syntax for that specifically.

2. With your current logic, you are also never actually fetching the value of the input fields. You're merely holding the reference to the element. You need to access the value of the input field in order to retrieve it.
3. You are not using valid variable declarations. You need to specify your variable declarations by using either `var`, `let`, `const`.

An example of getting the values a proper way would be:

```
const fname   = $('input[name="contactFname"]').val();
const lname   = $('input[name="contactLname"]').val();
const email   = $('input[name="contactEmail"]').val();
const subject = $('input[name="contactSubject"]').val();
```

Another way would be to use the `serialize()` method from jQuery. More about that [here](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Comment: Thank you a lot. That was the issue. missing `.val()` and incorrect syntax for `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
    <form action="./contactAction.php" method="POST" class="contact_form" id="cform" name="contactForm">
        <input type="text" id="contactFname" placeholder="Prenumele" />
        <input type="text" id="contactLname" placeholder="Numele" />
        <input type="text" id="contactEmail" placeholder="Emailul tau" />
        <textarea name="contactSubject" placeholder="Scrie mesajul tau" style="height: 200px"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="contactBtn">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div id="contactPage">Hello</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    $('#cform').submit(function() {
      contactFormValidation();
      return false;
    });
    
    function contactRequest() {
    fname = $("#contactFname").val();
    lname = $("#contactLname").val();
    email = $("#contactEmail").val();
    subj  = $("#contactSubject").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../contactAction.php",
        data: {contactFname: fname, contactLname: lname, contactEmail: email, contactSubject: subj},
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#contactPage").html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
    }
    
    function contactFormValidation() {
        $('#contactFname').attr('required',true);
        $('#contactLname').attr('required',true);
        $('#contactEmail').attr('required',true);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: your answer also is correct, 'cause you added .val() there but i haven't noticed it earlier.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - Tyler2P .

Comment: Good to see your problem is solved Virgiliu 